# I am trying to store data in sql server but i run into an error which i dont know how to fix

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to store the users name, email and their message on my contact page. When i run my website and go on the contact page and type all the details inside the contact form and click the send button (send button called submitBtn) i get the error you can see below in the image.

error message:
[image]

c# code: this c# code is for the send button.

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create the conection string and open the conn
            SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Fasthosts_MMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            //Open the connection string
            conne.Open();

            //Get all the values from the text boxes etc and pass them over to the DB
            string insertQuery = "insert into Contact(UserName, Email, Message) " +
                "values(@UserName, @Email, @Message)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conne);

            //Get values from the controls such as the text boxes and pass them over to the DB
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", tbUserName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", userMessage.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userEmail.Text);

            //This actually executes the query with the given values above.
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Dispose the connection string once the data has been passed over the DB
            conne.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception problem)
        {
            //throw Exception ;
            Response.Write("Error Message: " + problem.ToString());
            throw;

        }
    }
```

html code:

```
 <div id="contactForm" class="contactForm">
    <div id="formHeader" class="formHeader">
        <h1 id="message">Contact Us :)</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="formBody" class="formBody">
        <form action="homepage.aspx" method="POST" name="contactForm">
            <div class="inputContainer">
                <label for="userName">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-user"></i>
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbUserName" placeholder="John Smith" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <!--<input name="name" id="userName" type="text" placeholder="John Smith">-->
            </div>
            <div class="inputContainer">
                <label for="userEmail">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>
                </label>                
                <asp:TextBox ID="userEmail" placeholder="jsmith@domain.com" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="inputContainer">                
                <asp:TextBox ID="userMessage" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your message" runat="server" Height="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <!--<input id="submitBtn1" class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Send">-->
            <asp:Button ID="submitBtn" Class="submitBtn" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="submitBtn_Click" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

javascript code :

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var //GLOBAL VARIABLES
        input,
        container,
        //CSS CLASSES
        classSuccess = "success",
        classError = "error",
        //FORM VALIDATOR
        formValidator = {
            init: function () {
                this.cacheDom();
                this.bindEvents();
            },
            cacheDom: function () {
                //MAIN PARENT ELEMENT
                this.contactForm = document.getElementById("contactForm");
                //MAIN FORM ELEMENTS
                this.formHeader = document.querySelector("#formHeader h1");
                this.formBody = document.getElementById("formBody");
                this.inputContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("inputContainer");
                //USER INPUT ELEMENTS
                //INPUT FIELDS
                this.fields = {
                    userName: document.getElementById("userName"),
                    userEmail: document.getElementById("userEmail"),
                    userMessage: document.getElementById("userMessage")
                };
                this.submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
            },
            bindEvents: function () {
                var i;
                //RUN RULES ON SUBMIT BUTTON CLICK
                this.submitBtn.onclick = this.runRules.bind(this);
                //BIND EVENTS TO EACH INPUT FIELD
                for (i in this.fields) {
                    if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        //VARIABLES
                        input = this.fields[i];
                        container = input.parentElement;
                        //RUN RULES WHEN INPUT HAS FOCUS
                        input.onfocus = this.runRules.bind(this);
                        //RESET ERRORS WHEN CONTAINER IS CLICKED
                        container.onclick = this.resetErrors.bind(this, input);
                    }
                }
            },
            runRules: function (evnt) {
                var target = evnt.target,
                    type = evnt.type;
                //IF EVENT ON SUBMIT BUTTON
                if (target === this.submitBtn) {
                    //PREVENT FORM SUBMITTION
                    this.preventDefault(evnt);
                    //IF INPUT HAS FOCUS
                } else if (type === "focus") {
                    //RESET CLASSLIST
                    this.resetClassList(target.parentElement);
                    //RESET ERRORS
                    this.resetErrors(target);
                    return false;
                }
                //RESET CLASSLIST
                this.resetClassList();
                //CHECK FIELDS
                this.checkFields();
            },
            preventDefault: function (evnt) {
                //PREVENT DEFUALT
                evnt.preventDefault();
            },
            checkFields: function () {
                var i,
                    validCount = 0,
                    //EMAIL FILTER
                    filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                //CYLCE THROUGH INPUTS
                for (i in this.fields) {
                    if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        input = this.fields[i];
                        //CHECK IF FIELD IS EMPTY
                        if (input.value === "") {
                            //ADD ERROR CLASS
                            this.addClass(input, classError);
                            //CHECK IF EMAIL IS VALID
                        } else if (i === "userEmail" && !filter.test(input.value)) {
                            //ADD ERROR CLASS
                            this.addClass(input, classError);
                        } else {
                            //FIELD IS VALID
                            this.addClass(input, classSuccess);
                            validCount += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //IF ALL FEILDS ARE VALID
                if (validCount === 3) {
                    //SUBMIT FORM
                    this.submitForm();
                }
            },
            addClass: function (input, clss) {
                container = input.parentElement;
                //IF INPUT HAS ERROR
                if (clss === classError) {
                    //SHOW ERROR MESSAGE
                    this.errorMessage(input);
                }
                //ADD CLASS
                input.parentElement.classList.add(clss);
            },
            errorMessage: function (input) {
                var message;
                //IF USERNAME HAS ERROR
                if (input === this.fields.userName) {
                    message = "Please enter your name";
                    //ELSE IF USEREMAIL HAS ERROR
                } else if (input === this.fields.userEmail) {
                    message = "Please enter a valid email";
                    //ELSE IF USERMESSAGE HAS ERROR
                } else if (input === this.fields.userMessage) {
                    message = "Please enter your feedback";
                }
                this.renderError(input, message);
            },
            renderError: function (input, message) {
                var html;
                //GET INPUT CONTAINER
                container = input.parentElement;
                //RENDER HTML
                html = document.createElement("div");
                html.setAttribute("class", "message");
                html.innerHTML = message;
                //IF MESSAGE ELEMENT DOESN'T EXIST
                if (!container.getElementsByClassName("message")[0]) {
                    //INSERT MESSAGE TO INPUT CONTAINER
                    container.insertBefore(html, container.firstElementChild);
                }
            },
            resetClassList: function (input) {
                var i;
                //IF TARGETING SPECIFIC INPUT
                if (input) {
                    //GET INPUT CONTAINER
                    container = input.parentElement;
                    //REMOVE CLASSES
                    container.classList.remove(classError, classSuccess);
                    //FOCUS ON INPUT FIELD
                    input.focus();
                } else {
                    for (i in this.fields) {
                        if (this.fields.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            //REMOVE CLASSES FROM ALL FIELDS
                            this.fields[i].parentElement.classList.remove(classError, classSuccess);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            resetErrors: function (input) {
                //GET INPUT CONTAINER
                container = input.parentElement;
                //IF CONTAINER CONTAINS ERROR
                if (container.classList.contains(classError)) {
                    //RESET CLASSES
                    this.resetClassList(input);
                }
            },
            submitForm: function () {
                var waitForAnimation;
                //ADD SUCCESS CLASS
                this.contactForm.classList.add(classSuccess);
                //WAIT FOR ANIMATION TO FINISH
                this.changeHeader("Sent Succesfully");
                //WAIT FOR ANIMATION TO FINISH
                setTimeout(
                    this.changeHeader.bind(this, "Thank you for your feedback"),
                    1200
                );
            },
            changeHeader: function (text) {
                //CHANGE HEADER TEXT
                this.formHeader.innerHTML = text;
            }
        };
    //INITIATE FORM VALIDATOR
    formValidator.init();
})();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Why did you tag this as SQL Server?

Comment: mybe because it's to do with storing data in sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this in first line of page directive in source code

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```